# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <TSActivityMapVC: 0x81b1000>

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When I init `UITabBarController` where each tab include `UINavigationController` and each `UINavigationController` include `UIViewController` 
when in `UIViewController` I do something like

```
TSActivityDetailsVC * c = [[TSActivityDetailsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"TSActivityDetailsVC" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:YES];
```

I have animation, but when I press back button - I not have animation and get error

Log:

```
push view controller
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <TSActivityMapVC: 0x81b1000>.
back btn pressed
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <TSActivityDetailsVC: 0x81c85d0>.
```

init code:

```
-(UITabBarController *) createMainTabBarController{
UITabBarController * tabbarCntr = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabbarCntr setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[TSActivityMapVC alloc] init]],                                    
                                [[UIViewController alloc] init],
                                [[UIViewController alloc] init],
                                [[UIViewController alloc] init],
                                [[UIViewController alloc] init]
                                , nil]];
[tabbarCntr.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selection_indicator"]];
[tabbarCntr.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_background"]];    

return tabbarCntr; 
}
```

in `TSActivityMapVC` I perfom

```
TSActivityDetailsVC * c = [[TSActivityDetailsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"TSActivityDetailsVC" bundle:nil]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:YES];
```

surprisingly that when I go to another tab and return - after it - all works fine without errors

Comment: Just check if you do not push view controller twice. Set breakpoint at line [self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:YES];

Comment: `-(void)tst{
    TSActivityDetailsVC * c = [[TSActivityDetailsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"TSActivityDetailsVC" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:YES];
}`

controller added once

Comment: `-(void)beginAppearanceTransition:(BOOL)isAppearing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"**************begin app tr");
}
-(void)endAppearanceTransition{
    NSLog(@"**************end app tr");
}`

I added this into TSActivityMapVC (root view controller) but this method not calls when I try push or pop view controller over current controller
strange effect: after I go to another tab in UITabBarController  and back - after it all works and calls beginAppearanceTransition, endAppearanceTransition

Comment: Hm, strange. Your code looks ok. Could you share TSActivityMapVC.m?

Comment: yes http://snipt.org/zZig0

Comment: I Have next struct:
Window->UINavigationController->UITabBarController

Comment: Did u resolved this ?

Comment: Got exactly the same problem! How did you solved it? Search for hours to get this error solved :(

Answer (score 10):

I got the solution! I subclasses the `UITabBarController` and forgot to call the **super** of `viewWillAppear`. So the transition animation of the `UITabBarController` not finished.

This caused the the "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance"!

Comment: this was my problem. marry me :)

Comment: @Kai Burghardt: I love you!

Comment: I had the same problem as well, and resolved with this. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've reproduced your error. It seems that you are forgotten to call super in both methods.

```
-(void)beginAppearanceTransition:(BOOL)isAppearing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super beginAppearanceTransition:isAppearing animated:animated];
    NSLog(@"**************begin app tr");
}

-(void)endAppearanceTransition{
    [super endAppearanceTransition];
    NSLog(@"**************end app tr");
}
```

Hope your issue in this.

Comment: methods **-(void)beginAppearanceTransition:(BOOL)isAppearing animated:(BOOL)animated** and **-(void)endAppearanceTransition** not called - this method I added for check, but it's not called, methods call only when I tab from one tab to another and back - this code not solve problem

Comment: Calling super is important.