# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for UIViewController when selecting cells in tableView

Tags: ios, iphone, transition

*I know this has been asked a ton of times but I've tried some of the solutions in other questions and haven't been successful.*

In my app I have four tabs, each with their own `UINavigationController`. The first - `UserIndexController` is a UIViewController that contains a table. When a cell is selected, I initialize a new UIViewController and push it onto its `UINavigationController`. Here's that code:

```
tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
user = data[indexPath.row]
controller = UserViewController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle: nil)
controller.user = user
self.navigationController.pushViewController(controller, animated:true)
```

Once a cell is selected, almost as soon as the `UserViewController` is loaded I get:

`Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for UserIndexController.`

When I go back in the NavigationController from `UserViewController` to `UserIndexController`, I get:

`Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for UserViewController`.

Enter the insanity (at least to me): When my app loads, if I select any other tab before selecting a cell in my `UserIndexController`, then go back to my `UserIndexController` and select a cell, the unbalanced calls warning goes away.

So that's where I'm at. If anyone has any ideas or suggestions I'd love to hear them. Also I'm happy to provide more code if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my searching wasn't good enough. I found the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957765/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-tsactivitymapvc-0x81b) question. Essentially, in my `UITabController` I'm calling `viewWillAppear` but didn't call `super` in it. Doing that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your 'animated:' put NO then it will solved your problem.